# Probability of winning in coin toss game

Tags: probability

> Three persons (A, B, C) are playing a coin toss game. In each round,
> every person tosses a fair coin and who gets a different coin wins.
> For example, if A got T and two others got H - it means that A won the
> game. If they get same coins, for example three H's, it is a tie.
> There are up to 4 rounds if nobody wins before. If nobody wins the 4
> round (after 3 ties), it is a tie. What is the probability for A to win a single round? And the whole game?

My attempt of solving is OK. But let's see if there is another, more elegant way to solve this problem.

***For a single round (A wins):***
$P(round)=P(A=T)⋅P(B=H)⋅P(C=H)+P(A=H)⋅P(B=T)⋅P(C=T)$
$=\cfrac{1}{{2}}^3+\cfrac{1}{{2}}^3=\cfrac{1}{{4}}$

***For a whole game (A wins):***

$P(tie)=\cfrac{1}{{2}}^3+\cfrac{1}{{2}}^3=\cfrac{1}{{4}}$

$P(game)=P(round=1)+P(round=2)⋅P(tie)+P(round=3)⋅P(tie)⋅P(tie)+P(round=4)⋅P(tie)⋅P(tie)⋅P(tie)$

It means that A won round 1 OR round 2 OR round 3 OR round 4 (and had ties before). Now calculate:

$P(game)=\cfrac{1}{{4}}+\cfrac{1}{{4}}⋅\cfrac{1}{{4}}+\cfrac{1}{{4}}⋅\cfrac{1}{{4}}⋅\cfrac{1}{{4}}+\cfrac{1}{{4}}⋅\cfrac{1}{{4}}⋅\cfrac{1}{{4}}⋅\cfrac{1}{{4}}=\cfrac{85}{{256}}$

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with your way of solving it but it is longer. The only mistake you made is what I called out earlier. If you fix that, you should get the correct answer for the second part too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For a Single Round**

$A$ wins if both $B$ and $C$ get different toss than him. The probability is $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$

**For the Whole Game**

A round is tied if both $B$ and $C$ get the same toss as $A$. The probability is $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$. The probability that the whole game is tied is then $\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}$ and the probability that we have a winner is $1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}$. Since $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all equally likely to win the probability that $A$ win the whole game is then:

$$
\frac{1}{3}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{4}\right)
$$

Comment: +1 : elegant....